# Connecting to MSSQL from PHP securely with encryption?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I need to connect to a MSSQL database from PHP. However, as a server on a remote site is connected, I require the connection to be encrypted.

Is it possible to use encrypt the connection to the MSSQL server using only mssql extension for PHP or alternatively PDO?

Comment: You can always tunnel an unencrypted connection via an encrypted route - one approach may be to speak to whoever looks after your network between the two servers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is 3 things that are important when implementing a secure (encrypted) connection to MSSQL:

1. The options `Encrypt` and `TrustServerCertificate` are often used together.
2. By default the SQL server installs a self-signed certificate that it will use to encrypt connections - the self signed certificate are however open to attacks. So it should be replaced with one from a certificate authority (CA).
3. After replacing your certificate, you then set `Encrypt = true` and `TrustServerCertificate = false` (`TrustServerCertificate = true` will also work, but your connection will then be vulnerable to attacks)

Code-example from article *1:

```
$serverName = "serverName";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DbName",
                         "UID"=>"UserName",
                         "PWD"=>"Password",
                         "Encrypt"=>true,
                         "TrustServerCertificate"=>false);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

If you use PDO create an object and pass the relevant params.
For a more detailed explanation please see the following article:

*1 - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2011/03/08/sql-server-driver-for-php-connection-options-encrypt.aspx

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)

Comment: Could you explain further what you mean Erik? The code itself is just PHP, if your not the administrator of the MSSQL server you could contact the admin and ask him if its possible to setup a secure connection (youll need a certificate, but most web-hosting-providers offer this).

Comment: PHP sqlsrv requires SQL Server Native Client -http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php - so probably will not work on linux.

Comment: Note. I had to update to msodbcsql_17.4.2.1_x64.msi