# [MS][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:self signed certificate]

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, driver, sqlsrv

I am connecting to SQL Server with `sqlsrv` using PHP 8.0 on Centos7 with PLESK Onyx

When trying to connect got error:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08001
            [SQLSTATE] => 08001
            [1] => -1
            [code] => -1
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:self signed certificate]
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:self signed certificate]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08001
            [SQLSTATE] => 08001
            [1] => -1
            [code] => -1
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection. For solutions related to encryption errors, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2226722
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection. For solutions related to encryption errors, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2226722
        )

)
```

To connect I have something like this:

```php
$params = [
    "UID" => $username,
    "PWD" => $password,
    "Database" => $database,
    "TrustServerCertificate" => "yes"
];
if(sqlsrv_connect($host, $params)) {
    echo "connected..";
} else {
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    echo "<pre>";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

So I already use  `"TrustServerCertificate" => "yes"` as mentioned here for fixing that error > [ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1416F086]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71688125/odbc-driver-18-for-sql-serverssl-provider-error1416f086)

Answer (score 1):

In `sqlsrv_connect` when passing params `TrustServerCertificate` needs **true/false** value - not 'yes/no' (they use yes/no in Microsoft docs and it might be confusing sometimes) so:

```php
$params = [
    "UID" => $username,
    "PWD" => $password,
    "Database" => $database,
    "TrustServerCertificate" => true
];
if(sqlsrv_connect($host, $params)) {
    echo "connected..";
} else {
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    echo "<pre>";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

and that is how it works.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959492/connecting-to-mssql-from-php-securely-with-encryption) 3 things are important when implementing a secure (encrypted) connection to MSSQL:

1. The options Encrypt and TrustServerCertificate are often used together.
2. By default the SQL server installs a self-signed certificate that it will use to encrypt connections.
3. After replacing your certificate, you then set Encrypt = true and TrustServerCertificate = false (TrustServerCertificate = true will also work, but your connection will then be vulnerable to attacks)